# Notification not showing in electron react app

Tags: reactjs, notifications, electron, electron-forge

my notification was showing first time, but when I disable notifications from windows now its not showing.
also, notification.requestPermission() is always showing granted and not asking for permission.

on mac, notification is working first, but if I make app clean, that time notification not work and also not asking for any permission.

please give me a complete solution to implement the notification part.

Do I need to change anything on main file? or I can handle it using React component?

I am stuck on this problem for long and couldn't find any working solution. it will be really helpful If anyone give me a working solution

Thank you

```
if ("Notification" in window) {

  Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === "granted") {
     console.log(permission)
    }
  });
}
```